# trac: submit tickets from remote website

Tags: trac

i have trac setup on a machine that's different from my website, what i want to do is, everytime there is error(like when direct to a 404/500 pages) on the website, it will automatically submit a new ticket to server with trac installed, i tried to use the most intuitive way:

http://www.example/trac/newticket?reporter=anonymous&summary=test&type=defect&description=somethinginhere&action=create&status=new&priority=minor

but somehow it doesn't submit, but preview it, so i just wondering how can i overcome this. what i planning to do is using a img tag with src with the above address.

or is there a better way to it, i know installing xmlrpcplugin might solve my problem, but for now i just need a quick solution.

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question.  From my own experiences with Trac, I've found plugin installation to be very quick and easy.  Added to this, XML-RPC is a common protocol, and there is a client library for pretty much any language you're likely to be using.  I would have thought the XMLRPCPlugin would be the most effective way of handling this, and probably one of the quickest too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `__FORM_TOKEN` value that I think you need to get so that your ticket creation will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you debug it with FireBug and what happens locally? Maybe some extra value is set when you press 'create' instead of 'preview'?

Comment: Or maybe it uses POST instead of GET?

Comment: after careful consideration, i think setup an xmlrpc plugin is the best way to go, also it provide lots more functionalities. thanks guys for the advices.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [TracCmdScript](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracCmdScript).